# POWERBI: A circular dependency is detected issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a formula which provides me with an error: "A circular dependency is detected" - and I can't seem to understand why there is a circular dependency.

My assumption is the [Time duration fruit sold] which is a measure?

Any who can see the issue?

```
Scoring Column =
VAR NCT = CTL[FRUIT]
VAR filteredTable =
    FILTER (
        CTL,
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Time duration fruit sold] ) )
            && CTL[FRUIT] = NCT
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        RANKX ( filteredTable, CTL[Time duration fruit sold],, DESC ) - 1,
        COUNTROWS ( filteredTable ) - 1
    )
```

---

Measure:

```
Time Duration fruit sold =
VAR dispdate =
    MIN ( CTL[Site RTE Actual] )
VAR lastsoldthiscountry =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( CTL[Site Last Actual] ),
        ALL ( CTL ),
        SUMMARIZE ( CTL, CTL[FRUIT], CTL[Country Name] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( lastsoldthiscountry ) ) && NOT ( ISBLANK ( dispdate ) ),
        INT ( lastsoldthiscountry - dispdate )
    )
```

Comment: Is "Scoring Column" calculated in the CTL table?

Comment: Yes its a measure in the CTL table

Answer (score 2):

If "Scoring column" is a calculated column in the table CTL, then you do have a circular reference:

- In the calculated column, you refer to the measure "Time Duration fruit sold"
- In the measure "Time Duration fruit sold", you refer to the entire table CTL by using ALL(CTL). ALL function returns all columns, including the calculated columns like "Scoring Column". Since to calculate the measure, you need the column, and to calculate the column, you need the measure, you get the circular reference.

To solve this, make Scoring Column a measure instead of a calculated column.

More generally, avoid calculated columns at all - all columns in your data model should be pre-calculated either at the source (in a database), or in PowerQuery. Building them with DAX is a bad practice that should be avoided.

Comment: Hi @Rado this is great input and explains a lot. I will try to build it into power query but unsure if I can get the time duration fruit into power query as it's a measure

Comment: why do you want to use the time duration fruit measure to calculate the column? can't you compute it directly from the data in the table?

Comment: I would like to do so, but my intention is to have the the from first sold type FRUIT to latest sold in a specific country.

So in theory the time between first sold ORANGE to the last sold ORANGE in one specific country.

My data would have several different fruits and countries..

Comment: Then you shouldn't implement it as a column at all. Build it as a DAX measure.

Comment: Bu it is a DAX measure?
Time Duration fruit sold =
VAR dispdate =
    MIN ( CTL[Site RTE Actual] )
VAR lastsoldthiscountry =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( CTL[Site Last Actual] ),
        ALL ( CTL ),
        SUMMARIZE ( CTL, CTL[FRUIT], CTL[Country Name] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( lastsoldthiscountry ) ) && NOT ( ISBLANK ( dispdate ) ),
        INT ( lastsoldthiscountry - dispdate )
    )

Comment: I mean "Scoring Column"